# SQL Cumulative sum in a partition by

Tags: sql, partition-by

Consider a table with customers, sorted dates and amounts as follows

```
User    Date    Purchase
Joe  '2020-01-01' 10
Joe  '2020-02-01' 20
Joe  '2020-02-20' 20
Joe  '2020-03-15' 15
Lucy '2020-01-12' 5
Lucy '2020-02-15' 30
Lucy '2020-02-21' 20
Lucy '2020-03-05' 30
```

I would like to obtain a new column with the cumulative spent with the previous purchases, i.e.,

```
User    Date    Purchase Cum
Joe  '2020-01-01' 10      10
Joe  '2020-02-01' 20      30
Joe  '2020-02-20' 20      50
Joe  '2020-03-15' 15      65
Lucy '2020-01-12' 5        5
Lucy '2020-02-15' 30      35
Lucy '2020-02-21' 20      55
Lucy '2020-03-05' 30      85
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be:

```
select t.*,
       sum(purchase) over (partition by user order by date) as running_sum
from t;
```

Comment: Is the order by the key to achieve the running sum (instead of a total sum)?

Comment: @Jos . . . Yes.  The `order by` turns this into a running sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function :

```
sum(purchase) over (partition by user order by date) as purchase_sum
```

if window function not supports then you can use correlated subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t1.purchase) 
        from table t1 
        where t1.user = t.user and t1.date <= t.date 
       ) as purchase_sum
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `partition by`

```
    Select  User, Date, Purchase, 
    sum(purchase ) 
    over (partition by User order by user )
     From table
```